# Are suspensions for red cards, yellow cards carried between junior and senior UEFA competitions?

Tags: rules, football, uefa, suspension

If I understand the rules correctly, whenever a player receives red card, he is suspended for the next match. The same is true for 3 yellow cards. See, for example, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Euro_2016_qualifying_Group_C#Discipline).

I would like to know what happens in the situation illustrated in the following example.

During the match in [U-21 Euro qualifying play-offs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_UEFA_European_Under-21_Championship_qualification_play-offs) Slovak midfielder [Ondrej Duda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ondrej_Duda) was sent-off, see [here](http://www.uefa.com/under21/season=2015/matches/round=2000413/match=2015230/postmatch/report/index.html) or [here](http://int.soccerway.com/matches/2014/10/14/europe/uefa-u21-championship/italy-under-21/slovakia-under-21/1942923/). As of this moment, this was his last match for national team, see for example [his profile on soccerway](http://int.soccerway.com/players/ondrej-duda/250672/).

He was recently called up for the next fixture of the Slovak team in the [UEFA Euro 2016 qualifying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Euro_2016_qualifying_Group_C) against Macedonia. (Here is [a source](http://sport.sme.sk/c/7475302/kozak-nominoval-na-macedonsko-aj-tinedzera-dudu.html) in Slovak language.)

These are two different competitions, but both of them are organized by UEFA. I wonder whether he should be suspended in the senior team 's game or whether the suspensions are counted separately for senior and junior events. (Or, more generally, for various competitions.)

Even if the suspensions are not considered separately, another factor here might be that the U-21 qualifying tournament is already completed.

> TL;DR: If a player receives a suspension in U-21 competition, can he still play for senior's team? Is there a difference if the junior competition, where the player received suspension, is already completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ondrej Duda received the red card in an U-21 Euro Champions qualification match, so the suspension is defined in the regulation of that competition, available [here](http://www.uefa.org/MultimediaFiles/Download/Regulations/competitions/Regulations/01/88/95/94/1889594_DOWNLOAD.pdf) on UEFA's website.

Specifically article 22.01 states that:

> As a rule, a player who is sent off the field of play is suspended for the next
>   match **in the competition**. The Control and Disciplinary Body is entitled to augment this punishment. For serious offences the punishment can be extended to all UEFA competition categories

So the suspension does not apply at senior level (or in any other U-21 competition) and the player can play in the next game [unless The UEFA Disciplinary Body decided to ban the player from other competitions]